# Reading CSV file as gibberish

Tags: r

I downloaded a CSV file for a coursera lecture. Specifically, I downloaded data for fixed speed cameras from https://data.baltimorecity.gov/Transportation/Baltimore-Fixed-Speed-Cameras/dz54-2aru

The site provides the data neatly in CSV form. The excel data looks fine. However, when I read it into R, through read.table I get gibberish, such as:

```
     1. http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd>
    2   <!--[if IE 8]>
    3     <html xmlns=http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml xml:lang=en lang=en
    4           xmlns:v=urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml
    5           xmlns:og=http://opengraphprotocol.org/schema/ class=ie ie8 noBorderRadius noLinearGradient noCss3><![endif]-->
    6   <!--[if gte IE 9]>
    7     <html xmlns=http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml xml:lang=en
    8           xmlns:v=urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml
    9           xmlns:og=http://opengraphprotocol.org/schema/ lang=en class=ie><!      
[endif]-->
    10  <!--[if !IE]>-->
    11    <html xmlns=http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml xml:lang=en lang=en
```

Where did I go wrong?

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to know for sure where you went wrong since you didn't post your code, but it looks like you are trying to open up an xml file, not a csv.  I downloaded "Baltimore_Fixed_Speed_Cameras.csv" from the site you listed.  Export as just a plain CSV.  Then the following code worked to import it into R:

```
data <- read.csv("Baltimore_Fixed_Speed_Cameras.csv", header=T)

> head(data)
                         address direction      street  crossStreet               intersection                      Location.1
1       S CATON AVE & BENSON AVE       N/B   Caton Ave   Benson Ave     Caton Ave & Benson Ave (39.2693779962, -76.6688185297)
2       S CATON AVE & BENSON AVE       S/B   Caton Ave   Benson Ave     Caton Ave & Benson Ave (39.2693157898, -76.6689698176)
3 WILKENS AVE & PINE HEIGHTS AVE       E/B Wilkens Ave Pine Heights Wilkens Ave & Pine Heights  (39.2720252302, -76.676960806)
4        THE ALAMEDA & E 33RD ST       S/B The Alameda      33rd St     The Alameda  & 33rd St (39.3285013141, -76.5953545714)
5        E 33RD ST & THE ALAMEDA       E/B      E 33rd  The Alameda      E 33rd  & The Alameda (39.3283410623, -76.5953594625)
6        ERDMAN AVE & N MACON ST       E/B      Erdman     Macon St         Erdman  & Macon St (39.3068045671, -76.5593167803)
```

Open your file up in a plain text editor to make sure it really is just a vanilla csv file.